# On properties of open quantum dynamics and Lindbladians

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-information, time-evolution, open-quantum-systems

It is well known that the open quantum dynamics is governed by the Lindblad master equation
$$\partial_t{\rho}=\mathbb{L}(\rho)=-\frac{i}{\hbar}[H, \rho]+\sum_i \gamma_i\left(L_i \rho L_i^{\dagger}-\frac{1}{2}\left\{L_i^{\dagger} L_i, \rho\right\}\right),$$
where the solution is given by $e^{\mathbb{L}}(\rho)$, which is a complete positive trace-preserving (CPTP) map.

Taken as the counterpart of closed quantum dynamics (i.e., Hamiltonian evolution) $e^{-iHt}$, we know that the Hamiltonian is Hermitian.
It got me curious about what are the properties of the superoperator/map $\mathbb{L}(\cdot)$. Specifically, is it still completely positive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a channel, no, and it is not completely positive in general.
Nor you should expect it to be: the point of complete positivity is to ensure you get meaningful quantum states after the application of the channel. On the other hand, $\mathbb L$ gives you the derivative of the state, which won't be a quantum state in general. In fact, it's essentially a difference of quantum states, so I'd guess it can never even be positive (except in cases where it gives zero), let alone completely positive.

Consider for example the simplest case of a unitary time-independent dynamic, for which you have $\mathbb L(\rho(t))=-i[H,\rho(t)]$. The superoperator/quantum map $\mathbb L$ is thus $\mathbb L(X)\equiv -i[H,X]$. To check whether it's completely positive you can study its Choi, which is the operator
$$J(\mathbb L)\equiv \sum_{ij} \mathbb L(E_{ij})\otimes E_{ij}
= -i \sum_{ij} [H,E_{ij}]\otimes E_{ij},$$
where $E_{ij}\equiv |i\rangle\!\langle j|$.
For example, if $H=Z$ is a single-qubit Hamiltonian, then $[Z,E_{00}]=[Z,E_{11}]=0$, and $[Z,E_{01}]=2E_{01}$, $[Z,E_{10}]=-2E_{10}$. Thus
$$J(\mathbb L)= -2i (E_{01}\otimes E_{01}-E_{10}\otimes E_{10})
=-2i \begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0 \\0&0&0&0 \\ -1 &0&0&0\end{pmatrix}.$$
This matrix is clearly not positive semidefinite, which is equivalent to $\mathbb L$ not be completely positive. It's also not positive semidefinite on separable states, which means $\mathbb L$ is not even positive.